# How to combine sql::driver with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am writing a class which is going to connect to a database. So I have a global variable `std::shared_ptr<sql::Driver> driver;` because I am trying to learn how to do everything with smart pointers. But this always ends up in an problem, with every smart pointer so far, beacuse the destructor of `sql::Driver` is protected. So call like `driver.reset( )` Always end up in problems. How do I combine smart pointers with `sql::Driver`?

Comment: If the destructor of `sql::Driver` is _protected_, how are you supposed to delete it? How would you do it with plain pointers?

Comment: With plain pointers I would not delete it at all.

Comment: I'd guess that the `sql` namespace provides some concrete implementations for `sql::Driver` depending on the underlying RDBMS. To make the destructor protected is one way to protect applications from creating instances directly. In that case `shared_ptr<sql::Driver>` can't be used directly.

Comment: @Cheiron: If you would not delete it at all then you do not have ownership of the value it points to. If you do not have ownership, then what is the point of using a smart pointer that shares ownership?

Comment: May be it's possible to create a shared pointer in the main thread and use weak pointers for the accessors from other threads that just want to use the driver.

Comment: @g-makulik Shared_ptr was just an example, I also tried unique_ptr which came up with the same problem: at one point it wants to call the destructor, which is impossible.Hoe do I fic that?

Comment: @Cheiron In short, you need a unique / shared pointer of your concrete instance of `sql::Driver` and weak pointer implementations that refer to this (these won't ever call delete on the pointee). Valid type casts (`sql::ConcreteDriver` -> `sql::Driver`) should be possible.

Comment: @Cheiron: The error it is not in the code, it is in your understanding of it.

Comment: @Cheiron In case you don't see s.th. like `sql::ConcreteDriver` in this framework, you'll need to have an adaptor for naked pointers of `sql::Driver`. If this class implements a singleton, don't bother using pointer wrappers anyway.

Comment: @Cheiron _'because I am trying to learn how to do everything with smart pointers'_ BTW this is a mindset pitfall, see also the [Golden Hammer Antipattern](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/golden-hammer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, some classes are not intended to be managed by some external caller (i.e YOU).

Some classes are designed in a way where destruction occurs as a side effect:

```
void finished() {
  // Do something...
  delete this;
}
```

In other cases, these classes may be managed by some friend-class like an instance-manager or some sort.  A protected destructor might imply that you'll need to extend that class to gain permission.

Along these lines, singleton classes cannot be instantiated nor stored in a smart pointer of any kind since the constructor is typically private;

```
class Singleton {
private:
  Singleton() {  //...
  }
};
```

These types of classes are not compatible with smart pointers since it does not allow for proper reference counting.

Comment: So.. Just use naked pointers, because nothing can go wrong anyway?

Comment: They **are** compatible with smart pointers. Not so sure that is a smart idea, though...

Comment: @Cheiron In case `sql::Driver` represents a singleton you can just use naked pointers, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The section [Connector/C++ Connecting to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html) says that you don't have to `delete driver` explicitly, this is why you get `error: ‘virtual sql::Driver::~Driver()’ is protected`. So the solution is to use a dumb pointer for `driver` instead of a smart one. (Only for `driver`!)

And `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` have no problems with smart pointers:

```
// a dumb pointer is used here intentionally, no need to delete it
sql::Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
// shared_ptr also works
unique_ptr<sql::Connection> con( driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root") );
```

Note that in [Connector/C++ Complete Example 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) and [Connector/C++ Complete Example 2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html) `driver` is not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is just **plain wrong**. You mention that if you were using plain pointers, you wouldn't be calling `delete` at all. That, together with the fact that the destructor is `protected`, hints to the fact that you do not have ownership of the pointer value.

Since you do not have ownership, you have nothing to do with `unique_ptr` and/or `shared_ptr`, which deal with unique and shared ownership of the value pointed to.

If you insist on going on that route, and adding considerable overhead to keep reference counts on synchronization for something you do not even need, then you can do it. Both `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` can take a *Deleter* parameter. In your case, as you already mention, it would be a *no-op*.

```
struct noop_deleter
{
    void operator ()(void const* ptr) const { /*no-op*/ };
};

shared_ptr<sql::driver>{ driver_ptr, noop_deleter{} };
unique_ptr<sql::driver, noop_deleter>{ driver_ptr, noop_deleter{} };
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's protected, it is either meant to be inherited from or you're supposed to call a static Destroy() function (or similar) for destruction. For the former, you do something like:

```
class MyDriver : public sql::Driver
{
public:
    virtual ~MyDriver() {} // calls sql::Driver::~Driver() implicitly

    // ...
};
```

Perhaps some concrete classes in your SQL library fulfills this for you. In that case, look for how to use them.

For a destroy function, you use a custom deleter. Assuming something like this:

```
namespace sql
{
    class Driver
    {
    public:
        static Driver* Create(); // factory
        static void Destroy( Driver* );
        // ...
    protected:
        Driver();
        virtual ~Driver();
    };
}
```

you would do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<sql::Driver> driver( 
    sql::Driver::Create(), 
    sql::Driver::Destroy );
```

In general, however, your [destructors should either be public and virtual or private and non-virtual](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/22/gotw-5-solution-overriding-virtual-functions/).

A third option is that your sql::Driver is meant to be a singleton, though the dtor should still be private there unless it's designed for inheritance.